# adding an existing AWS machine to JUJU

Tags: juju, aws

I'm trying to simulate a situation in which a client has server with no Juju installed and we want to create a juju enviroment to controll them.So I have a new created machine

```
foo
```

the docs say

> Manual provisioning is the process of installing Juju on an existing machine and bringing it under Juju's management; currently this requires that the machine be running Ubuntu, that it be accessible via SSH, and be running on the same network as the API server.

so I tried the command

```
juju add-machine aws.foo
```

with no success. Any hints?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a cloud using a pre-existing machine, you would do the following:

```
  juju bootstrap manual/192.168.1.128 mycloud
```

substituting in the accessible IP address of the machine in question.

This will create a controller environment for Juju, but it still won't have any machines to deploy applications on. These are added like so:

```
  juju add-machine ssh:ubuntu@192.168.1.129
```

again, substituting in the correct IP address (and assuming there is a user already configured on the machine called 'ubuntu' to which you have the corresponding ssh key.

However, using Juju in this manner forgoes some of the benefits of having an on demand cloud environment. If you have access to an AWS account for example, it is much more useful to use that directly.

This is actually all covered [in the official documentation](https://docs.jujucharms.com/stable/en/clouds-manual). (I'm not sure where the quote you mentioned comes from)